# Sort Order in FileZilla: Ignore Case?

Tags: macos, filezilla

Is there a way to get FileZilla to ignore case for sorting file and folder names?  I want to see all the filenames that start with "D" next to the ones that start with "d."

Comment: I'm curious, is there any particular reason you're using FileZilla on OS X and not e.g. Cyberduck?

Comment: @Daniel Beck, yeah, looks much more impressive now than 2 years ago when I tried it last. That may be another way to solve the problem :)

Comment: @Randolf Richardson I appreciate the edits to the text, but I changed the title back to title capitalization. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, the only reason that I can think of is "synchronized browsing" which I use a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option, since this is hard-coded.

It's in the current source code, `src/LocalListView.cpp` and `src/RemoteListView.cpp`:

```
inline int CmpName(const CLocalFileData &data1, const CLocalFileData &data2) const
{
#ifdef __WXMSW__
    return data1.name.CmpNoCase(data2.name);
#else
    return data1.name.Cmp(data2.name);
#endif
}
```

FileZilla only sorts case-insensitively on Windows due to `__WXMSW__` (**wx***Widgets* **M***icro***s***oft* **W***indows*) being defined there.

You can always download the sources, change these few lines, and recompile yourself.

Comment: Wow, thanks SO MUCH @Daniel Beck, I think I'll do that.